# External Hard Drive is only recognized as a USB-device

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, usb, external-disk, system-profiler

When I plug in my WD Elements Hard Drive, it is only recognized as a USB3.0 connection (see image). I don't see any drive showing up in the Disk Utility, but I do see the USB showing up. Could this be an indicator that the drive itself is dead? Are there any tricks i can do in the terminal for this? [image]

Comment: Can you give the results of terminal command : `diskutil list external`. Else have you try use an another cable if possible?

Comment: diskutil list external does not return anything. The cable does work without another WD drive, then diskutil list external does return the other drive.

Comment: Have you try this WD drive on another Mac or PC?

Comment: @Jean_JD tried it on my other PC, does recognize the drive under device mangement, but does not recognize the disk in the windows version of disk utility..